# How do I cast a ForeignKey constraint on a column to another table with multiple-column Primary Keys?

Tags: sql

Question as per stated in the title.

For example:

```
Table_Groups:
  - name (pri key)
  - other_tables (ForeignKey to Tables)

Tables
  - name (pri key)
  - color
  - country_of_make (pri key)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a table with multiple primary keys.  Do you mean one primary key over multiple columns?

Regardless, the columns of a foreign key must match *all* the columns of the referenced table's primary key.  So if your primary key has two columns (name, country_of_make), you need the foreign key to have those two columns too.

A foreign key can also reference a column (or set of columns) with the UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got the answer:

FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES table(c,d)